# how to deserialize a session data inside a 'click event' , that the session data is received from another function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, serialization, deserialization

```
   public partial class PaymentForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 

public class CartItem
 {
     public string name { get; set; }
     public decimal price { get; set; }
     public int quantity { get; set; }
 }

 public class CartDataRequest
 {
     public List<CartItem> cart { get; set; }
     public decimal finalAmount { get; set; }
 }

 
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static void StoreCartData(string cartData1)
 {
     try
     {
         CartDataRequest cartData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CartDataRequest>(cartData1);
         List<CartItem> cartItems = cartData.cart;
         decimal finalAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(cartData.finalAmount);

        HttpContext.Current.Session["CartData"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cartData1);

         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cart data stored successfully in ASP session.");
         
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CartData contents: " + HttpContext.Current.Session["CartData"]);     
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error storing cart data: " + ex.Message);
         throw;
     }
 }

}
```

i passed data from client side to server side page by using ajax and web method. i can deserialize & serialize the data here at the first function.then passing it to the click event.

```
 protected void btnSubmitOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
        // Retrieve cart data from session
         string storedCartData = (string)Session["CartData"];
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Stored Cart Data: " + storedCartData);

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(storedCartData))
         {
             CartDataRequest cartDataRequest = new CartDataRequest();
             // Deserialize the JSON string into CartDataRequest object
             CartDataRequest cartData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CartDataRequest> (storedCartData);  /* at this point the deserialization failed.jumps to error message */
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CartData new contents:" + cartData);
        }
        else
        { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Stored Cart Data is empty "); 
         }
     catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error processing cart data: " + ex.Message);
    string script = "alert('An error occurred during the process')";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
}
```

in this section, i couldn't deserialize the received session. it jumps to the error message at the catch exception. Message at debug panel is "'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll".

I need some guidance on how to resolve it and access the data inside the session. Then only i can access the data & store it into SQL

TIA.

Comment: What is the value of `storedCartData`?

Comment: sir, in the debug panel it shows the value of storedCartData as,   "{"cart":[{"name":"Chocolate Milk","price":5.5,"quantity":2}],"finalAmount":"11.00"}"

Comment: Your `finalAmount` from the JSON is a string, but your `finalAmount` in the `CartDataRequest` class is a `decimal`. The types are conflicted.

Comment: So, in you WebMethod, you are serializing a string into another string? On this line, you are doing this: HttpContext.Current.Session["CartData"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cartData1); where cartData1 is already a string. Did you mean to just assign the cartData1 to the session object?

Comment: @YongShun sir, I passed data from client side by using ajax, i formed the data in float format  ' var finalAmount = parseFloat($('#finalBillingTextBox').val());'  before putting into ajax. so, i used decimal in the 'CartDataRequest' at the server side.

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper I forgot to note that sir. Thanks for notifying it. I rectified the error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can shove the de-serialized object into session. No need to serialize it again.

Also, you have not tagged your web method as having session enabled.

So, you need this:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(enableSession:true)]
```

Without above, then your code to save into session will not work.

And thus, you can do this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["CartData"] = cartData1;
```

Now, later on in code, you can get the object out using this:

```
  cartData1 = (List<CartItem>)session["cartData"];
```

So, place the object into session, and then you are free to pull out that object and no serializing is required at that point in time.

So, store the object in session, and not the Json string.

You only need to serialize the object again if you sending it back to the client side at some point in time.

So, for the general use of that object in code behind then saving the object should work just fine.